# Why COOKIE return different value both index url and subdirectory domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie

I try to using $_COOKIE in php for generating unique visitor ID. I choose $_COOKIE because it is always available as long the time that I want althought the device used by visitor is turn off.

My problem is when I echo COOKIE value with same key it's return different both root domain and subdirectory. Some directory return same value with root domain but some of them return diferent.

Here is the flow :

```
http://example.com
```

return same COOKIE value with

```
http://example.com/cart
```

but this one return diferent COOKIE value with same key used above

```
http://example.com/detail/my-product-name-uri
```

Here is my generating code for the COOKIE

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['ID']))
setcookie(
  "ID",
  uniqid(),
  time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  '/'
);
```

I using CODEIGNITER btw and generating COOKIE in index.php file int the root.

Comment: show us the cookie generation code

Comment: here is my code
`if(!isset($_COOKIE['ID']))
 setcookie(
   "ID",
   uniqid(),
   time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
   '/'
 );`

Comment: You probably have set a different cookie value some time before under that specific path … Clear all your cookies in the browser, then call your script that sets the cookie again (and make sure that is the _only_ time a cookie is set), and then visit both paths again.